# Pytables Undo vs Pandas hdf5 write

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I am processing large amounts of financial data from csv files and storing them to pytables.  This process is very slow, I think because of converting the panda dataframe a row at a time into a pytable row and appending.

But, in order to keep the pytable on disk from corruption, I utilize the mark and undo feature of pytables.  Each time I'm certain the writes are all completed for a days worth of data, I mark the table.   Each time the app is run, I undo to the latest mark.

I'd like to experiment with using pandas write to hdf5 file capability as it may be substantially faster.

Is there a way to still use pytables mark and undo feature, if I use pandas to write directly to an hdf5 file?

Comment: This is not implemented directly, though you *can* use underlying PyTables methods. However, why are you not writing to a separate file, check that it has the correct/data, then repeat. Then you can easily concat these (I suppose with the mark/undo), if you really really need. The risk of disk corruption is exceedenly low, better to simply try it, if it works (as it will most of the time), you are done, and if their IS a problem. Then just start over.